# AWS API gateway as subscriber to Google Cloud pubsub

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to subscribe to a Google Cloud pub-sub topic (which will push notifications about user's inbox changes). Since Google requires a HTTPS endpoint I created an AWS API Gateway endpoint. But I'm unable to add this endpoint as a subscriber.

I get an error saying - **"Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later."**.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Azeem

Comment: Have you followed the prerequisites in 'Registering other endpoints' [1] (verifying and registering the domain)? Can you outline each step you took so that we can know if you missed something? How are you adding the endpoint, and where does the error come from? [1] https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/prereqs#push_endpoints

Comment: Azeem, I know it's been a while, but is there a chance you solved this and could post your own answer? It may help others out in the future.